# Correctly escaping quotation marks

Tags: bash, shell, python, quoting

I have the following command:

```
python -c 'import crypt; print(crypt.crypt("$Password", crypt.mksalt(crypt.METHOD_SHA512)))'
```

Where `$Password` is a shell variable. How do I correctly expand it as a variable, and not have it treated as a literal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't as that would be a code injection vulnerability and also avoid passing passwords in arguments to commands, as they then become public by showing in the output of `ps` and they are sometimes logged in some audit logs.

Using environment variables is usually better:

```
PASSWORD="$Password" python3 -c 'import os, crypt
print(crypt.crypt(os.getenv("PASSWORD"), crypt.mksalt(crypt.METHOD_SHA512)))'
```

(here using the `VAR=value cmd` syntax as opposed to `export VAR` so the environment variable is passed only to that one command invocation).

Comment: Since `Password` is already an environment variable, instead of assigning it to another environment variable, you could just use it as-is or, if necessary, `export` it.

Answer (score 2):

Don't.

```
python -c 'import sys; import crypt; print(crypt.crypt(sys.argv[1], crypt.mksalt(crypt.METHOD_SHA512)))' "$Password"
```

Comment: How does this work? If I change `$Password` there to `$Password1`, then the command still passes even though I have not set anything to $Password1. Will `$Password1` be treated as empty?

Comment: Yes, since it has been quoted for the shell.